# dynamically changing chart series extjs 4

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, charts, extjs-mvc

I'm using Extjs 4 with the MVC architecture.

I have a python script that outputs this Json Data :

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "inAnalysis": 3, 
        "inQuest": 2, 
        "inDevelopment": 6, 
        "total": 12, 
        "inValidation": 1, 
        "Month": 1303
    }, 
    {
        "inAnalysis": 1, 
        "total": 5, 
        "Month": 1304, 
        "inDevelopment": 4
    }
], 
"success": true, 
"metaData": {
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "inAnalysis"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "inQuest"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "inDevelopment"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "inValidation"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "isDuplicate"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "New"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "total"
        }
    ], 
    "root": "data"
}
```

}

I want the fields of my MetaData to be used as the chart series, so I have a store like this :

```
Ext.define('Proj.store.ChartData', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
autoload: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : 'data/getParams.py',
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        fields:[]
    }),
    root: 'data'  
}
```

And to add series to the chart I did this :

```
var chart = Ext.widget('drawchart');
var fields = [];

chartStore.each(function (field) {
    fields.push(Ext.create('Ext.data.Field', {
        name: field.get('name')
    }));
});
chartModel.prototype.fields.removeAll();
chartModel.prototype.fields.addAll(fields);

var series = [];
for (var i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
    var newSeries = new Ext.chart.BarSeries({
        type: 'column',
        displayName: fields[i].name,
        xField: ['Month'],
        yField: fields[i].name,
        style: {
            mode: 'stretch',
            color: this.chartColors[i + 1]
        }
    });
    series.push(newSeries);
    chart.series = series;
};

chart.bindStore(chartStore);
chart.redraw();
chart.refresh();
```

But It's not working, I think the fields array is always empty... 
Any help would be appreciated:

Comment: Could you find any solution to your question?

Comment: please paste your code on fiddle with dummy json

Answer (score 7):

Swapping or reloading a store would be easy, however you'd have a very hard time reconfiguring axes and series a posteriori... Ext's chart just don't support that. It would be possible to replace the axis in the `myChart.axes` collection, and same for series, and then with a careful study of the code, replace remove the existing sprites, etc. However that's a fool's path since, for once your code will be very fragile against future evolutions of Ext's chart code (which happen), and second there is a far more easier and reliable solution. That is creating a new chart, remove the old one, put the new one in its place, and pouf! The user won't see the difference.

You're not giving a lot of information about your code, so I'll work a solution out of the [Bar chart example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/charts/Bar.js).

First, you need to fix your store:

```
Ext.define('Proj.store.ChartData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    //autoload: true,
    autoLoad: true, // there was a type in there
    fields: [], // was missing
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'data/getParams.py',
        // better to inline the proxy (lazy init)
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
            ,root: 'data' // and root is an option of the reader, not the proxy
        }
//      reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
//          fields:[]
//      }),
//      root: 'data'
    }
});
```

Then, let's enrich your response a bit in order to minimize the prior client-side knowledge of the model to none. I've added a `totalField` and a `categoryField` to the `metaData` node, that we'll use for the axis and series:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "inAnalysis": 3,
            "inQuest": 2,
            "inDevelopment": 6,
            "total": 12,
            "inValidation": 1,
            "Month": 1303
        },
        {
            "inAnalysis": 1,
            "total": 5,
            "Month": 1304,
            "inDevelopment": 4
        }
    ],
    "success": true,
    "metaData": {
        "totalField": "total",
        "categoryField": "Month",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "Month"
            },
            {
                "name": "inAnalysis"
            },
            {
                "name": "inQuest"
            },
            {
                "name": "inDevelopment"
            },
            {
                "name": "inValidation"
            },
            {
                "name": "isDuplicate"
            },
            {
                "name": "New"
            },
            {
                "name": "total"
            }
        ],
        "root": "data"
    }
}
```

Please, notice that the proxy will catch the [`metaData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-metaProperty) in the response automatically and reconfigure its store's (implicit) model accordingly... so you don't need your gloubiboulga to do it yourself. It is also worth noting that the reader will keep a copy of the raw response data in its [`rawData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-property-rawData) property; that will be useful to get the custom information we've added.

Now that we have a proper store that will receive a detailed response, let's use it:

```
new Proj.store.ChartData({
    listeners: {
        load: replaceChart
    }
});
```

That will trigger the `replaceChart` method, that will create a brand new chart from the meta and data given by the server and destroy and replace the old one. Here's the function:

```
function replaceChart(chartStore) {

    // Grab the name of the total & category fields as instructed by the server
    var meta = chartStore.getProxy().getReader().rawData.metaData,
        totalField = meta.totalField,
        categoryField = meta.categoryField;

    // Build a list of all field names, excluding the total & category ones
    var fields = Ext.Array.filter(
        Ext.pluck(chartStore.model.getFields(), 'name'),
        function(field) {
            return field !== categoryField && field !== totalField;
        }
    );

    // Create a pimping new chat like you like
    var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        store: chartStore,
        legend: true,
        axes: [{
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: [totalField]
        }, {
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'left',
            fields: [categoryField]
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'bar',
            axis: 'bottom',
            label: {
                display: 'insideEnd',
                field: fields
            },
            xField: categoryField,
            yField: fields,
            stacked: true // or not... like you want!
        }]
    });

    // Put it in the exact same place as the old one, that will trigger
    // a refresh of the layout and a render of the chart
    var oldChart = win.down('chart'),
        oldIndex = win.items.indexOf(oldChart);
    win.remove(oldChart);
    win.insert(oldIndex, chart);

    // Mission complete.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear lines cache of unused series:

```
Ext.Array.each(chart.series.items, function(item){
            if(!item.items.length){
                item.line = null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: An answer to this post has already received a bounty from several years ago - please provide a little additional information as to why this is a helpful answer in the context of the post and available answer.